Modifying Default Styles of DT Package Download Buttons in R Markdown
I'm not happy with the default colors and fonts of the download buttons (copy, excel, pdf, csv, print, etc.) in the option settings of the datatable in the DT package in R Markdown. How can I modify the style of these buttons in R?
I want to change the size and color of the buttons as I desire.
